# What is the proper format/ notation for JSON Web Tokens?

Tags: jwt

A JSON Web Token is supposed to have the following format:

```
token = encodeBase64(header) + '.' + encodeBase64(payload) + '.' + encodeBase64(signature)
```

When I use the jsonwebtoken node.js function to create a token:

```
jsonwebtoken.sign({username : "admin", password : "admin"}, publicKey, { algorithm:'HS256' });
```

It produces the following output:

```
eyJhbGciOiJIUzI1NiIsInR5cCI6IkpXVCJ9.eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY2OTIxMDE0MH0.Cj2-vgNkw2xChXMe5YjIrH9UYH6-pL7ArSERBVJO-zE
```

When you decode the header, you get:

```
'{"alg":"HS256","typ":"JWT"}'
```

But decoding the payload gives a padding error because the padding has been omitted. Only when the payload is changed to (correct number of '=' added):

```
eyJ1c2VybmFtZSI6ImFkbWluIiwicGFzc3dvcmQiOiJhZG1pbiIsImlhdCI6MTY2OTIxMDE0MH0=
```

Does it decode correctly to:

```
'{"username":"admin","password":"admin","iat":1669210140}'
```

And the signature cannot be decoded because it contains multiple '-', which is an invalid base64 character.

My question is this:

If each section is meant to be base64 encoded, then why is the padding ommitted from the payload, and what is the strange syntax of the signature?

I tried finding information on the [jsonwebtoken GitHub repository](https://github.com/auth0/node-jsonwebtoken) , but couldn't find an explanation.

EDIT: After doing some more research, I discovered that JWT uses Base64URL encoding, not Base64 encoding. Will update this post once I have more information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JWTs are not encoded in plain Base64, but in **Base64url**.
For this version, padding is optional, and it uses different charset: '-' instead  of '+' and '_' instead of '/'.

Sources:

https://jwt.io/introduction
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Variants_summary_table